# Fan-in channels to single channel

Tags: go, channel

I have several channels c1, c2, c3, c4 ..., How can I collect all data from those channel into one channel?
my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func putToChannel(c chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 15)
    c1 := make(chan int, 5)
    c2 := make(chan int, 5)
    c3 := make(chan int, 5)
    go func(){c <- <-c1}()
    go func(){c <- <-c2}()
    go func(){c <- <-c3}()
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(3)
    go putToChannel(c1, wg)
    go putToChannel(c2, wg)
    go putToChannel(c3, wg)
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("Receive:", i)
    }

    fmt.Println("Finish")
}
```

I want to compose all the data from c1, c2 ... to c but it not works

Comment: Why not just use a shared channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) has a good writeup of how to do "Fan-In" of channels, including stopping short.

There's a problem with these lines:

```
go func(){c <- <-c1}()
go func(){c <- <-c2}()
go func(){c <- <-c3}()
```

Each of these will receive **one** value from `cx` channel and send that one value into `c`.

You need a method that looks like this;

```
func merge(cs ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan int)

    // Start an output goroutine for each input channel in cs.  output
    // copies values from c to out until c is closed, then calls wg.Done.
    output := func(c <-chan int) {
        for n := range c {
            out <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to close out once all the output goroutines are
    // done.  This must start after the wg.Add call.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

This method relies on the fact that the channels `cs...` that are being passed to `merge` are closed when there are not more values to be sent.

This means you will need to update your `putToChannel` method also

```
func putToChannel(c chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer close(c)
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}
```

One final thing that it's worth noting is that in general; try and encapsulate the function that creates & send to a channel and the function that closes a channel to be the same function. This means you will never try and send on a closed channel.

Instead of:

```
c1 := make(chan int, 5)
go putToChannel(c1, wg)
```

You can do;

```
func generator() (<-chan int) {
    c := make(chan int, 5)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
             c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }() 
    return c
}
```

Your main method will look something like:

```
func main() {
    var cs []<-chan int

    cs = append(cs, generator())
    cs = append(cs, generator())
    cs = append(cs, generator())

    c := merge(cs...)
    for v := range c {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit, as you can see below.

Basically, in this example, there are three steps that need to be taken:

1. Put the values inside `c1`, `c2`, and ,`c3` and don't forget to close them once you're done with putting values in.
2. Iterate over every channel that need to be merged into `c` with `for-range` to put the values in `c`. After the `for-range` loop you need to put `wg.Done()` so you can signal the goroutine to eventually close `c` after iterations through every channel is done. If by any chance you haven't closed one of the channels that are to be merged into `c`, you would get `all goroutines are asleep - deadlock` error.
3. Close the `c` channel once everything is done

Here is the modified code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func putToChannel(c chan<- int) {
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    //close the channel after putting values in
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 15)
    c1 := make(chan int, 5)
    c2 := make(chan int, 5)
    c3 := make(chan int, 5)

    output := func(ch <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        //you need to iterate over the channel
        for n := range ch {
            c <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(3)
    go putToChannel(c1)
    go putToChannel(c2)
    go putToChannel(c3)
    go output(c1, wg)
    go output(c2, wg)
    go output(c3, wg)

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("Receive:", i)
    }

    fmt.Println("Finish")
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func putToChannel(c chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 15)
    c1 := make(chan int, 5)
    c2 := make(chan int, 5)
    c3 := make(chan int, 5)
    send := func(c1 chan int, c2 chan int) {
        for {
            value := <-c2
            c1 <- value
        }
    }
    go send(c, c1)
    go send(c, c2)
    go send(c, c3)
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(3)
    go putToChannel(c1, wg)
    go putToChannel(c2, wg)
    go putToChannel(c3, wg)
    wg.Wait()
    for i := 0; i < 15; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Receive:", <-c)
    }

    fmt.Println("Finish")
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Receive: 1
Receive: 2
Receive: 3
Receive: 4
Receive: 5
Receive: 1
Receive: 2
Receive: 3
Receive: 4
Receive: 5
Receive: 1
Receive: 2
Receive: 3
Receive: 4
Receive: 5
Finish
```

Answer (score 0):

a **clean method**:

assume we have a infinite sender like this:

```golang
func msgSender(msg string) <-chan string{
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for {
            ch <- msg
            time.Sleep(300*time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    return ch
}
```

**NOTE**: `msgSender()` return a receive only channel

we want fan-in two (or more) sender in one channel:

```golang
func fanIn(){
    receiveOnlyCh1:= msgSender("msg1")
    receiveOnlyCh2:= msgSender("msg2")

    fanInCh := make(chan string)
    go func(){
        for{
            select {
            case fromSender1 := <-receiveOnlyCh1:
                fanInCh <- fromSender1
            case fromSender2 := <-receiveOnlyCh2:
                fanInCh <- fromSender2
            }
        }
    }()

    go func(){
        for {
            fmt.Println(<-fanInCh)
        }
    }()
}
```

output:

```
msg1
msg2
msg2
msg1
msg2
msg1
msg2
msg1
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BhScg6nqphq

Answer (score 0):

a solution involving the [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package to provide a re usable function.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
)

func putToChannel(c chan<- int) {
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {

    var cs []interface{}
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        c := make(chan int, 5)
        cs = append(cs, c)
        go putToChannel(c)
    }

    c := fanin(cs...).(chan int)
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("Receive:", i)
    }
    fmt.Println("Finish")

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/b_vbLzpCDFo

It appears slightly simplified because it does not need the apparent use of a  WaitGroup. Each worker has the simple responsibility to `close` the output channel when the work is done. `fanin` will figure things out given that previous precondition.

The `fanin` function expects an empty interface slice of identical channel type, it looks for the first item to determine the type of the output channel. It then create the output channel, spawns one goroutine for each input channels, and forward items from each input channels to the output channel.
A WaitGroup is involved to close the output channel when all input channels were also closed.
Note that it panics if the input channel slice is empty.

It looks like this

```golang
// fanin fanins all input channels into a single channel.
// fanin is func(input ...chan T) (chan T)
func fanin(inputs ...interface{}) interface{} {
    // note: because we take in variadic of interface, we cannot receive the trailing error channel...
    if len(inputs) < 1 {
        panic("no channels to fanin")
    }
    rinputs := []reflect.Value{}
    for _, input := range inputs {
        rinputs = append(rinputs, reflect.ValueOf(input))
    }
    out := reflect.MakeChan(reflect.ChanOf(reflect.BothDir, rinputs[0].Type().Elem()), 0)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < len(rinputs); i++ {
        rinput := rinputs[i]
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                x, ok := rinput.Recv()
                if !ok {
                    break
                }
                out.Send(x)
            }
        }()
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        out.Close()
    }()
    return out.Convert(rinputs[0].Type()).Interface()
}
```

If you keep drying things up you may end up with a `fanout` function like below.

https://play.golang.org/p/0Zi9h4XPbbV

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
)

func putToChannel() chan int {
    c := make(chan int, 5)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    return c
}

func main() {
    for i := range fanout(3, putToChannel).(chan int) {
        fmt.Println("Receive:", i)
    }

    fmt.Println("Finish")
}
```

With such implementation the `fanout` function looks like

```golang
// fanout spawns n instances of workers.
// worker is a func() chan A
// it fanins all output channels and return a chan A
// fanout is func(n int, worker func() chan A) chan A
func fanout(n int, worker interface{}) interface{} {
    rworker := reflect.ValueOf(worker)
    if rworker.Kind() != reflect.Func {
        panic("not a func")
    }
    var outchans []interface{}
    var in []reflect.Value
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        res := rworker.Call(in)
        outchans = append(outchans, res[0].Interface())
    }
    return fanin(outchans...)
}
```

Comment: some more here https://play.golang.org/p/wCkZV1LyBHy